# Create an effect when two items are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to create a drawing tool for myself where I select a category, a time limit, and after clicking a start button, a randomized slideshow will play each image will for the time I've selected.

Right now I'm trying to set up jQuery so that the div containing the slideshow is hidden until I press start. Then, the slideshow appears (along with some controls like a pause button). My problem is that I'm not sure how to set up jQuery for this. I need to set it up so the slideshow plays after I press start, but play for a certain time based on which radio button I choose. I hope this makes sense.

Here's the html for the slideshow page:

```
<table style="width:50px height:200px">
    <ul class="controls">
        <li><img class="prev" src="skip-backward.png" /></li>
        <li><img class="pause" src="pause.png"></li>
        <li><img class="next" src="skip-forward.png"></li>
        <li><img class="stop" src="stop.png"></li>
    </ul>
</table>
<!--Pics-->
    <div id="pics">
        <img class="allppl" src="___and_one_for_the_girlies_by_Sadiel47.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="___Sheer_Stock_02____by_Symplig0th.png"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="___Sheer_Stock_03____by_Symplig0th.png"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="___Sheer_Stock_04____by_Symplig0th.png"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="___Sheer_Stock_06____by_Symplig0th.png"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="___Sheer_Stock_09____by_Symplig0th.png"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="a0e54_large.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="007-10-.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="007-11-.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="007-12-.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="007-7-.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="007-8-.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="007-9-.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="male_fighter_10_by_bobbistock.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="male_fighter_3_by_bobbistock.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="male_fighter_9_by_bobbistock.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="relaxing.jpg"/>
        <img class="allppl" src="Rendan_Touch_by_cugot12.jpg"/>
    </div>    
<!--Time Lengths-->    
<table class="times" style="width:90%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="nums">
            <td>30 secs</td>
            <td>1 min</td>
            <td>90 secs</td>
            <td>2 mins</td>
            <td>5 mins</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="allppl30" id="30s" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="allppl1" id="1min" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="allppl90" id="90s" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="allppl2" id="2min" /></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="allppl5" id="5min" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!--Start & Home Buttons-->    
<span class="lbuttons" id="start"><button type="button">Start</button></span>
<span class="lbuttons" id="home"><button type="button">Home</button></span>
```

And here's jQuery. I'm using the Cycle 2 plugin for the slideshows. I put my past attempts in comments so I could better keep track of what was working and what wasn't.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#pics').hide();
    $('button#start').click(function () {
        $('#pics').show(function () {
            jQuery(this).cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                next: '#pics',
                speed: 30000,
                random: 1
            });
        });
    });

    /*
            Basic Click- WORKS (Pics appear when start is clicked and cycle isn't present)
    $('#start').click(function () {
        $('#pics').show();
    });
            First Attempt- DOESN'T WORK
    if ($('button#start').is(':clicked')) {
        $('#pics').show();
    }
    if ($('input#30s').is(':checked')) {
        $('.times').hide();
        jQuery('#pics').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            next: '#pics',
            speed: 30000,
            random: 1
        });
    } */
    if ($('div#pics').width() >= 1000 && $('div#pics').height() >= 1100) {
        $('div#pics').css('max-width', '90%');
    }
});
```

If it's not already obvious, at this point, I'm just typing different things to see what happens.

EDIT: I figured out part of the problem: I need to use "timeout" not "speed" in my commands for the slides. Speed affects the speed of transitions, not the amount of time the slide is on screen.

The timer works when I use numerical input for timeout (e.g. typing "timeout:30000" causes the images to stay on screen for 30 seconds), but I can't get it to work with the variable NibbCNoble suggested.

Here's the new code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('#pics').hide();
    $('.play').hide();
    $('#start').click(function () {
        var speedval = $("input[name=ppl]:checked").val();
        $('#pics').show(function () {
            $(this).cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                next: '#pics',
                timeout: speedval,
                random: 1
            });
        });
    });
    $('.pause').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.play').show();
    });
    $('.play').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.pause').show();
    });
    /*        Basic Click- WORKS
    $('#start').click(function () {
        $('#pics').show();
    });
            First Attempt- DOESN'T WORK
    if ($('button#start').is(':clicked')) {
        $('#pics').show();
    }
    if ($('input#30s').is(':checked')) {
        $('.times').hide();
        jQuery('#pics').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            next: '#pics',
            speed: 30000,
            random: 1
        });
    } */
    if ($('div#pics').width() >= 1000 && $('div#pics').height() >= 1100) {
        $('div#pics').css('max-width', '90%');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your slideshow is setup, but the part I can get you in the right direction on is the radio buttons.  If you want to use those radio buttons to feed in values to the time that is spent on each slide, you need to set the value to an input that can be input, such as however many seconds.

[Here is a fiddle that I started with the radio buttons value getting selected](http://jsfiddle.net/srdufd59/)

the HTML portion that I changed a bit

```
   <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="30" id="30s" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="60" id="1min" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="90" id="90s" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="120" id="2min" /></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="ppl" value="300" id="5min" /></td>
```

and the javascript portion:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
'use strict';
$('#pics').hide();
$('button#start').click(function () {
    var speedval = $("input[name=ppl]:checked").val();
    $('#pics').show(function () {
        jQuery(this).cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            next: '#pics',
            speed: speedval,
            random: 1
        });
    });
});

/*
        Basic Click- WORKS (Pics appear when start is clicked and cycle isn't present)
$('#start').click(function () {
    $('#pics').show();
});
        First Attempt- DOESN'T WORK
if ($('button#start').is(':clicked')) {
    $('#pics').show();
}
if ($('input#30s').is(':checked')) {
    $('.times').hide();
    jQuery('#pics').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        next: '#pics',
        speed: 30000,
        random: 1
    });
} */
if ($('div#pics').width() >= 1000 && $('div#pics').height() >= 1100) {
    $('div#pics').css('max-width', '90%');
}
```

});

Comment: The slideshow started working when I changed 'button#start' to '#start', but the time limit is about 5 seconds regardless of which radio button I select.